# How to compute similarities based on co-occurrence matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, cosine-similarity, find-occurrences

I have an item-item matrix (1877 x 1877). The values in the matrix represent the number of times two items occurred together. How can I determine the similarities between two items?
Through reading, i found few options. However i am not sure about these approaches. Any inputs to get started is appreciated.

1. Use cosine to compute sim between two vectors
2. Turn this into a graph, use measures like simrank to compute similarity - may use the occurrence count as a weight between two nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [spatial cosine similarity](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html). Alternatively you could calculate [jaccard's similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for each item pair.

After calculating either similarity matrix (affinity matrix) you can use a spectral (or spatial) clustering algorithm, such as [sklearn's spectral clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html) algorithm to group those items.

Answer (score 1):

You can thread it as 1877 items with 1877 features each. If two items are similar, than they co-occurrences will be similar. Given that you might use [`NearestNeighbors`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors) in order to find closest one. There are may metrics available.

Also, reprocessing the data may help you. I do not know it's distribution but you might want to normalize values into range [0;1] or doing sth like that.

Comment: if i get you right, i use cosine to compute sim between columns in my matrix? columns are regarded as features..regarding normalization, are you referring to rescaling each column to have a length of 1? from sklearn.preprocessing import *; normalized_X = normalize(X, axis=0, norm='l1')

Answer (score 1):

If your **co-nonoccurence matrix** is *symmetrical*, you don't need to normalize it. You can refer to this paper for gain more information about normalization of *symmetrical* and *asymmetrical* co-matrices:
*Leydesdorff, L. and Vaughan, L., 2006. Co‐occurrence matrices and their applications in information science: Extending ACA to the Web environment. Journal of the American Society for Information Science and technology, 57(12), pp.1616-1628.*
please, click [hear](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/asi.20335)